# Possible sources for CHS disk geometry

Tags: c, ioctl, block-device

I am trying to determine the "correct" CHS from a block device:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/hdreg.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argv, char **argv) {
    int r;
    int f;
    struct hd_geometry g;

    f = open(*(argv+1), 0);
    if (f < 0) {
        printf("open fail: %d\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    r = ioctl(f, HDIO_GETGEO, (void*)&g);
    if (r == -1) {
        printf("ioctl fail: %d\n", errno);
        return 2;
    }
    close(f);
    printf("c: %d\nh: %d\ns: %d\nstart: %d\n", g.cylinders, g.heads, g.sectors, g.start);
    return 0;
}
```

Using it on a usb stick I get:

```
c: 1020
h: 247
s: 62
start: 0
```

However, `fdisk --units=cylinders -l /dev/sdc` gives:

```
Geometry: 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1020 cylinders
```

Probably it's getting its information from somewhere else. So which other sources might it use?

And is there a way to determine the "correct" one? As far as I understand, CHS is set completely arbitrarily by hw manufacturers in these modern times.

Environment :

- linux 4.15.13
- glibc 2.26-11
- fdisk; util-linux 2.31.1

fdisk libs:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeb7be8000)
libfdisk.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfdisk.so.1 (0x00007fe4b040f000)
libsmartcols.so.1 => /usr/lib/libsmartcols.so.1 (0x00007fe4b01dd000)
libtinfo.so.6 => /usr/lib/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007fe4aff70000)
libreadline.so.7 => /usr/lib/libreadline.so.7 (0x00007fe4afd22000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe4af96b000)
libblkid.so.1 => /usr/lib/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007fe4af71d000)
libuuid.so.1 => /usr/lib/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fe4af516000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe4b0896000)
```

Comment: Reading the `man` page on `fdisk` and searching for `cylinder` yields some funny results. Apparently this is somewhat of an unknown, and deprecated, though I don't know why the two calculations are different.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the tools that deal with CHS just make up their own values.  Here's the function that's producing the values you see in `fdisk` [from a util-linux repo on github](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/b428eb14a8f92afbad388aecf91779a486ba208e/libfdisk/src/alignment.c).

```
static void recount_geometry(struct fdisk_context *cxt)
{
    if (!cxt->geom.heads)
        cxt->geom.heads = 255;
    if (!cxt->geom.sectors)
        cxt->geom.sectors = 63;

    cxt->geom.cylinders = cxt->total_sectors /
        (cxt->geom.heads * cxt->geom.sectors);
}
```

As you can see, it just pegs `heads` and `sectors` to fixed values, then computes the `cylinders` value so that the total drive capacity works out.

The `HDIO_GETGEO` ioctl returns numbers that come from the specific device driver you're using.  If you're curious, you can drill down through `drivers/scsi/sd.c` and figure out where your specific values originate.

Consider reading the [wikipedia page on CHS addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector), too.  These fields don't really mean anything - especially on a solid-state USB stick!